# Relationship between submodules of $F[x]/(x^n)$ and $F^n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, module-isomorphism

I am working on the following question:

> Let $F$ be a field.  Let $F^n$ be an $F[x]$ module where $x$ acts on $(a_1, ..., a_n) \in F^n$ by $x \cdot (a_1, \dots, a_n) = (0, a_1, \dots, a_{n - 1})$.  Prove $F[x]/(x^n) \cong F^n$ as $F[x]$-modules.  Use this isomorphism to describe the $F[x]$-submodules of $F^n$.

My idea so far:

Let $\varphi\colon F[x] \to F^n$ be given by $\varphi(p(x)) = \varphi(\sum_{i = 1}^m a_i x^{i - 1}) = \sum_{i = 1}^m x^{i - 1} (a_i, 0, \dots, 0)$.  I believe that $\varphi$ is a surjective $F[x]$-module homomorphism with $\ker\varphi = (x^n)$.  So by the first isomorphism theorem, $F[x]/(x^n) \cong F^n$.

However, I am unsure how to use this isomorphism to describe the $F[x]$-submodules of $F^n$.

Comment: What are the $F[x]$-submodules of $F[x]/(x^n)$?

Comment: @Angina Seng If you view $F[x]$ as a ring, I believe that ideals in $F[x]/(x^n)$ are of the form $(x^i)/(x^n)$, $0 \le i \le n$.  I believe that if $I$ is an ideal of $R$ then ${}_R I$ is a submodule of ${}_R R$?  So would the submodules of $F[x]/(x^n)$ be simply $(x^n)/(x^i)$? I guess I just need a little help connecting this with $F[x]$-submodules of $F^n$. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track.